# How to prevent Targetted Jump Links from opening in a new Tab?

Tags: wordpress, page-jump

When Links in the Page/Posts in my website are clicked, they correctly open in a new tab. But when the Anchor Texts or Page Jumps targetted to Top or any specific spot in the Page is clicked, that is also opening in a new tab.This may be because, I have inserted the Code '' in the Head using the Plugin Insert Headers and Footers, (after reading some tips like this) How to prevent the Page Jump Links from opening in a new Tab. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [target](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) attribute for the `<a>` tag:

`<a target="_self" href="">MyLink</a>` = Open in the same tab window

`<a target="_blank" href="">MyLink</a>` = Open in new tab or window

If this doesn't work for you, then there's probably a bug in the plugin you're using... You probably either want to fix it or find another solution that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. My question was not correctly presented by me. I have inserted the Code '<base target="_blank">' in the Head using the Plugin Insert Headers and Footer, to enable opening the links in the post/page in a new tab. Now I need the Page Jump Links to open in the same tab, at the  specific targetted spot, without affecting the code that enables to open other Links in the new tab. Thanks

Comment: The target tag can go on the individual link. I've updated my answer to further clarify this.

Comment: Thank you. The answer worked for me. In case it is useful for other developers I attach the solution with the hyperlink code and the anchor code in HTML.  Step 1. Place the anchor in the desired section of the page using tag <a> as follows: <a id="report"></a>, then Step 2. Locate the hyper link in the desired section as follows:  <a rel="noopener" target="_self" href="#report">Go to report column </a>. In the example "report" is the name of the anchor. Note that _self has the effect of not opening a new tab and staying on the same page.